# Extract data from html table to csv by simple html dom

Tags: php, html, csv, simple-html-dom

I want to extract data from html table to csv. I load html data and process by simple html dom. This is my sample data

```
<tr id="ST1" class="foo"><td class="CLASS_0_NO_NEED"><span class="icons">pet</span></td><td class="name"><span class="name_icons">tom</span></td><td class="p_type"><span class="type_icons">cat</span></td><td class="p_sex"><span class="s_icons">male</span></td><td class="p_year"><span class="y_icons">2</span></td>
<td class="p_height"><span class="Height" alt="2|3">3</span></td>
<td class="p_weight"><span class="Weight" alt="3|5">5</span></td>
<td class="CLASS_7_NO_NEED">Close</td></tr>

<tr id="ST2" class="foo"><td class="CLASS_0_NO_NEED"><span class="icons">pet</span></td><td class="name"><span class="name_icons">sam</span></td><td class="p_type"><span class="type_icons">dog</span></td><td class="p_sex"><span class="s_icons">male</span></td><td class="p_year"><span class="y_icons">1</span></td>
<td class="p_height"><span class="Height" alt="4|4.5">4.5</span></td>
<td class="p_weight"><span class="Weight" alt="5|7">7</span></td>
<td class="CLASS_7_NO_NEED">Close</td></tr>
```

I use simple html dom this code.

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_contents('testpet.html');
$html = str_get_html($html);

header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sample.csv');

$fp = fopen("sample.csv", "w");
foreach($html->find('tr') as $element)
{
  $td = array();
   foreach( $element->find('td') as $row)
  {
    $td [] = $row->plaintext;
  }
  fputcsv($fp, $td);
}
fclose($fp);

$html->clear();
unset($html);
```

The output of sample.csv isn't what I really want because there is "$DATA+space" in each fields.

```
"pet ","tom ","cat ","male ","2 ","3 ","5 ",Close
"pet ","sam ","dog ","male ","1 ","4.5 ","7 ",Close
```

Moreover I do need some alt(Height.alt and Weight.alt) value to csv and I don't want some class (icons). The filnal cvs should be like this.

```
"tom","cat","male","2","2","3","3","5"
"sam","dog","male","1","4","4.5","5","7"
```

Is it possible? Please help.

Comment: What's your question? If it's how to remove trailing space, then the answer is `trim()`

Answer (score -1):

sir, u dont want to use jquery and javascript bcoz its simple in that.

but u can try php function fputcsv()

Example #1 fputcsv() example

```
<?php

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
The above example will write the following to file.csv:
aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd
123,456,789
"""aaa""","""bbb"""
```

Comment: Maybe I did not make it clear for you.
My procedure is
1. load a html file "petdata.html" > 2. simple dom porcess > 3. output cvs

Comment: yeah got it sir looking for it.Problem is that different sites giving different ways.